# Possible bisection method?

Tags: numerical-methods

For the polynomial: p(x) = a0 + a1*x + ..... + an*x^n

Define: R = (|a0| + |a1| + ... + |an-1|)/|an|

suppose that R > 1. show for every root α of p that |α| ≤ R.

Consider the cases where |α| ≤ 1 and |α| > 1 separately.

So I'm unsure of how to even start this problem. I need to show for every root alpha of p that |alpha| less than or equal to R.

Comment: I would start with the observation that neither $R$ not the roots of the polynomial change if you multiply the polynomial with a non-zero number. Thus you can just assume $a_n=1$ and get rid of the division. The case $\left|\alpha\right|\le1$ is easily handled by the condition $R>1$. This leaves the case $\left|\alpha\right|>1$. I'd use the fact that for $a_n=1$, $p(x) = (x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$ and use that to express the $a_n$ in terms of $\alpha_n$, and look whether I can find some inequalities that can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

First, if $|\alpha|\le1$ then obviously $|\alpha|\le R$ since you are told $R>1$.

Now suppose that $|\alpha|>1$.  Since $\alpha$ is a root of $p$ we have
$$a_n\alpha^n+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1\alpha+a_0=0$$
and so
$$\eqalign{|\alpha|^n
  &=\Bigl|\frac{a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1\alpha+a_0}{a_n}\Bigr|\cr
  &\le\Bigl|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\Bigr||\alpha|^{n-1}+\cdots
  +\Bigl|\frac{a_1}{a_n}\Bigr||\alpha|+\Bigl|\frac{a_0}{a_n}\Bigr|\cr
  &\le\Bigl|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\Bigr||\alpha|^{n-1}+\cdots
    +\Bigl|\frac{a_1}{a_n}\Bigr||\alpha|^{n-1}
    +\Bigl|\frac{a_0}{a_n}\Bigr||\alpha|^{n-1}\cr
  &=R|\alpha|^{n-1}\cr}$$
and so $|\alpha|\le R$.